# Text box validation using selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to selenium and want to validate the data enter by the user is correct or not.
For example
There is email text box so i will ask user to enter email address.Than i want to validate that the data entered by the user is in correct email address format or not

Example 2
For contact no all the data should be numeric

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Email Validation in selenium IDE

 <tr>
        <td>verifyValue</td>
        <td>id=Emailid</td>
        <td>regexpi:^[_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4})$</td>
    </tr>


    Try this..

    Thank you..
```